# GitHub Action not triggering on push

Tags: github-actions

I can't for the life of me figure out why my GitHub Action isn't triggering on push. For context: I have a data file that is updated daily and pushed to the `test` branch with a timestamp commit message. I am trying to use this timestamp in a Dynamic Badge for my README. Everything works fine when the workflow is run manually (except, of course, I don't get the event data I am hoping to obtain when the action runs on the trigger.)

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test
    paths:
      - 'data/Sales.csv'
env: 
  BADGE_MESSAGE: ${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}

jobs:
  create-badge-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - name: Create Dynamic Badge
       uses: schneegans/dynamic-badges-action@v1.1.0
       with:
         auth: ${{ secrets.GIST_PAT }}
         gistID: 0123456789              #Not actual gist ID
         filename: test.json
         label: Last Refresh
         message: $BADGE_MESSAGE
         color: orange
```

And yes, I've tried putting the branch name in quotes and updating the `paths:` to `- '**.csv'` and the action still does not trigger.

Comment: Is this yaml file in `.github/workflows/`? Mind the plural form. Can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Yes, ```.github/workflows/main.yml```

Comment: try putting the branch name in single quotes like it's show [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-to-specific-branches-occurs)

Comment: Also in the same link, they note that **Note: If you use both the branches filter and the paths filter, the workflow will only run when both filters are satisfied.**

Comment: @MattiaRighetti As mentioned at the end of my post, I did try putting the branch name in quotes and it still did not trigger on push to the `'test'` branch.

Comment: Is your workflow committed to your default branch?

Answer (score -1):

There must be something else wrong - all you have here in this workflows is just fine.

You can see it working here:
https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/actions/runs/1860382530

For this commit:
https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/commit/f3f8dd20fa780746441c7b6623b6a2a9929aa70d

It's exact copy of workflow from your question.

I would expect you are pushing a file with different name - keep in mind some systems will be case-sensitive - so pushing `data/sales.csv` won't work properly.
Another idea is that you pushing it to wrong branch or you have wrong path to the file.
You have to push to `test` branch and with `data/Sales.csv` - it only triggers workflow if both are true.

Short answers is - workflow is fine as it is - no brackets needed.
I could help more seeing the repository with this workflow and exact commits being done.